# MarkLogic and Write once read many

Tags: marklogic

Is it possilbe to store/import data on a WORM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once_read_many) device within MarkLogic? Is it possible to have different store types within MarkLogic (WORM and not WORM, SSD, etc..)? I didn't find any documentation about that. Can anyone point me to further information regarding this topic?

Answer (score 1):

The feature of more than one type of storage device is called 'Tiered Storage'.

The documentation is found here:
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/tiered-storage

I know of no native way to handle WORM devices in MarkLogic under a forest because, by design, data is moved around internally.  However, you could write files out of MarkLogic onto another mounted device.

Comment: Adding to this, HDFS is WORM and can host forests. That's the only such case I'm aware of.

Comment: I took the context of the original question to be about WORM devices (cdrom, single-write flash drives, etc) - as in 'if I write the data, it will not change'.  Even though HDFS is based on WORM -  which is  beneficial for streaming large amounts of data, My take on this in the context above is : (1), a MarkLogic forest mounted on HDFS is not suddenly WORM (the data is changeable like any other data) and (2), there is quite a bit of muscle-work in the connector, which even though it appears as a native filesystem (hdfs://), its is still through a connector and in my mind, not 'native'.

Comment: Although by acronym HDFS is WORM, by usage it is not, since you can delete files on HDFS, but you cannot delete files on WORM drives. MarkLogic cannot operate with forests residing directly on WORM drives. You can archive forests to WORM however, and you may (although we don't test this) be able to mount them read-only directly from a WORM drive.